# Error on loading Genymotion Device on OS X Mavericks

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, osx-mavericks, genymotion

I have been using Genymotion on OS X 10.8 but after I updated it to Mavericks, the Genymotion device does not work properly. The three buttons which should be at the bottom appear at the top. However the touch is uneffected. Thus while the buttons are shifted to top, they are sensitive to touch only when touched at bottom.
Here is a sample screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

**Edit** - One of the answers suggest that the problem might also depend on the Mac model I am using. I am using a 13" Macbook Retina Pro.

**Edit 2** - A couple of applications are also running upside down. For example, the Music App

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Same experience on Mac Mini gen 2011 (5,1 model). Had to reinstall VirtualBox because it didn't work any more after the upgrade to Mavericks. Didn't solve the problem outlined in the question.

Comment: Same on Macbook Air 2011.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the problem should occur with integrated graphics (Intel) but not with dedicated one (such as with MBP Retina with Nvidia GPU).
We, at Genymotion, found the problem and have a patch ready. We're in the process of testing it, there will be an update ASAP.

EDIT : The 1.3.1 update is now out, it should solve this display problem - https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/changelog/

PS: I'm working for Genymotion

Comment: Please do paste the link to the patch here!!

Comment: The new patch fixes the bugs for me.

Answer (score 3):

Close all virtual machines which is related to genymotion;

Remove ***genymotion.app*** ***genymotion_shell.app*** from Applications folder.

Find genymotion ghost files and remove them.

By default installation;

cd /Users//.GenyMobile 

rm -rf .Genymobile

[Download genymotion 1.3.1](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/) which has the correction for this problem.
‘On Mac OSX 10.9, the graphic render of Android window was upside down. This issue is fixed.’

Install genymotion with .dmg file as usually.

Than try to run your device from android studio || eclipse plugin

Ps: If the problem goes on 
try ;
        1-remove all old vm machines 
2-Remove virtualbox engine. (If you can't be sure to remove fully virtualBox I suggest to use [Appzaper](http://www.appzapper.com))
3-[Download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and reinstall it. 
3-Restart your os (This step is required.)
4- Than try to run your device from android studio || eclipse plugin

I hope this helps .

Comment: I follow steps in this post, but I uninstall my virtualbox by clicking VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool in DMG.And It works.

Answer (score 2):

Cite from genymotion on Google+:

> Genymotion works in Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks! :)
>
> After migrating, there is sometimes bugs with VirtualBox. Uninstalling and reinstalling it should fix most of them.
>
> There is a known bug where the notification bar and the navbar are wrongly positionned. We are aware of it and working on it. Thank you to all the people that already reported it, the data provided did help us greatly.

I updated virtual box to the latest version und reinstalled genymotion, this worked out for me.

Comment: How did you update VirtualBox? I'm on 4.3 now and still no luck.

Comment: I am running the latest version of VirtualBox and reinstalled GenyMotion with no luck.

Comment: Okay this is strange. I'm not shure if I updated VirtualBox or if I deinstalled the old one and installed the new, but I had a problem after the Mavericks update from GoldMaster to the offical release.

Maybe you try a new clean start...delete the VirtualBox App, Genymotion App and the ".Genymobile" folder (in your Home).
After that restart and install VirtualBox und Genymotion.

Good Luck!! BTW: I have a normal(not retina) Macbook Pro 15"

Answer (score 2):

A direct link to the download (you'll still need a Genymotion account): https://ssl-files.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-1.3.1/genymotion-1.3.1.dmg

This is a minor patch that fixes the display issues caused by Mavericks: 
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/changelog/

> Corrections
>
> ```
> On Mac OSX 10.9, the graphic render of Android window was upside down.
> ```
>
> This issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

hehe :)

let me guess, u also have a 13" MacBook Pro?
Maybe it belongs to the graphics driver, i face the same problem.

But i can also say: It does not occur on a 15" MacBook Pro (Company Device)

Tip for better experience: You can disable the Big Navigaton Buttons in Emulator Settings, and use the Nav. Buttons on the Genymotion Emulator (Right Side)

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/

I talked to them right now at the DroidCon UK -> bug is fixed,
update released: Version 1.3.1 :) as mentioned :) by the "other user" :) (sorry don't see his name here in edit view: ))

Comment: I will use your tip as a temporary solution for now. This at least corrects the mismatch in touch sensitivity which was incorrect previously.

Comment: as told from the guy, the problem is when using the internal graphics card and acceleration, with the dedicaded graphics card it (should) work without problems .. :)