# Genymotion, "Unable to load VirtualBox engine." on Mavericks. VBox is setup correctly

Tags: android, macos, osx-mavericks, genymotion

I keep getting the following error:

[image]

I have reinstalled, deleted and tried about EVERYTHING to get Genymotion to work again.

I do not have the device I need, but Genymotion was PERFECT for the job, until Mavericks update I have been fighting to get it to work again.

MacBook Pro, Retina 13-inch, Early 2013.
i5, 8gb.

I'm running version 1.3.1 for os x.
I do have Virtualbox 4.3 installed with Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.0-89960.vbox-extpack too.

My Virtualbox starts up normally without ANY errors.
I tried Environment variables putting vbox on my $PATH, all sorts of things.
Nothing works!

I have no idea what to do anymore, anyone out there had similar problems and fixed it ?

EDIT:
LOG:

```
Oct 28 09:49:36 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  **** 
Oct 28 09:49:36 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 1.3.1 
Oct 28 09:49:36 [Genymotion] [Debug] Network request to URL:  "/launchpad/last_version/mac/x64/" 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion server informs that version  "1.3.0"  is available from  "https://ssl-files.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-1.3.0/genymotion-1.3.0.dmg" 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] Version: "1" 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Error] Genymotion is newer than the database... how is possible? 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] Library loaded with success 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel" 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7fbae3bf" 
Oct 28 09:49:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage path (default value): "VBoxManage" 
Oct 28 09:50:09 [Genymotion] [Debug] Can't run VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") 
Oct 28 09:50:09 [Genymotion] [Warning] QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
Oct 28 09:50:09 [Genymotion] [Error] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins/" 
Oct 28 09:50:09 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.
```

EDIT 2:

VBoxManage list hostonlyifs

Prints the following:

```
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_BASE_STREAM_WOULD_BLOCK (0x80470007) - Stream operation would block (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
```

Comment: Could you please share with us your log files (https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-logs) ?

Comment: I assure you I do have VBox installed and it's working 100%

Comment: If you open a "terminal" and just type "VBoxManage list hostonlyifs", what's the output ?

Comment: I assume you already tried to reinstall VirtualBox ?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned all VBox files out. Restarted, reinstalled and tried older versions of VBox too.

Comment: I have the same. I guess this is worth a bug report

Comment: According to me, the bug report should go to VirtualBox, as this is the "VBoxManage list hostonlyifs" which doesn't work, apparently because the vbox COM server doesn't start.

Comment: Were you running Genymotion as the admin user on your machine?

Comment: Just if anyone is having the same Problem on a Windows Computer. An easy restart of my System just solved the Problem.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by running the following command:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

In later versions, the command is

```
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
```

Make sure you've unblocked VirtualBox's kernel extensions in System Preferences->Security and Privacy->General (You'll get a popup when you install VirtualBox).

Comment: where is the /Library/StartupItems/ on mavericks? Can't find anything like that.

Comment: I have this problem, and upside down buttons on mavericks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561669/error-on-loading-genymotion-device-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP and this fix worked for me also.

Comment: This could solve the problem once, but need to run the command every time i restart the computer. Is there an once-and-for-all way?

Comment: I had to restart VirtualBox and Genymotion after running this for it to work as well.

Comment: This was very helpful, but i agree with Chris.Zou. I am running virtual box 4.02 and about to upgrade to a newer version. That might address the issue long term. Not sure yet, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: I experienced this more than one time and I think this may be permanent solution, You can upgrade virtualbox .exe(For windows) or .dmg(For Mac) or .deb(For Linux) file and install newer version of virtual box will solve your problem and If you are already have latest vesion then you can simply re-install it. Download Newer version link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

Comment: I get `sudo: /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox: command not found`.

Comment: Closest thing I can find on El Capitan with VBox 4.3.20 is `sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart`, which returns among other things the error: `/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).` The system console also shows a plethora of interesting though obtuse error messages. Not entirely sure, but it looks to me like the VBox kext (kernel extension) may be incompatible with newer versions of OSX.

Comment: additionaly you can restart using sudo service virtualbox restart

Comment: I downloaded the "without VirtualBox" option (https://www.genymotion.com/download/), and still I get this error ...

Answer (score 76):

Eventually, you might not have anything in your `/Library/StartupItems`.

Using the following command helps :

```
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
```

It worked for me on two different Mavericks installs.

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading to Mavericks. Previously I was able to use Amit's answer.

Comment: restarted and had to run this command again....is there some way to make this fix permanent?

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me

Answer (score 24):

**Update:** Genymotion's 2.5.1 release (https://www.genymotion.com/#!/release-notes/251#251) seems to have fixed this issue. (thanks for the heads up @Roger!)

---

For those that may be stumbling upon this a bit later, I resolved this by installing VirtualBox 4.3.28 (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3). The new 5.0.0 and 4.3.30 versions didn't work for me with Genymotion 2.5. None of the above solutions worked :(

It's also worth noting that at the time of writing, Genymotion's FAQ states the following:

> However, for performance reasons, we recommend using version 4.3.12

Comment: thanks! small correction - that url is https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3

Comment: This needs to be pushed to the top of the list!

Comment: I think the Genymotion 2.5.1 release fixed this actually: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/release-notes/251#251

Comment: Genymotion 1.0.5 released and works well VirtualBox 5.x on OSX
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/release-notes/253_p105

Comment: 2.5.2 works with 4.3.30, but still no 5.0.n support.

Answer (score 19):

You need to restart VirtualBox service you can do it with this:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

If in this path is empty you can use:

```
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
```

After I use Parallels I always need to do it.

Answer (score 17):

On Ubuntu GNU/Linux:

`sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me in Win 7 is to remove the Host-only Network (in Oracle virtual box preferences menu [CTRL+G] -> Network -> host only networks). Genymotion will recreate it automatically at the next virtual device start.

Comment: Be cautioned. When I deleted the file, my machine immediately shutdown.  Save your work!  Started up fine, and I uninstalled both and reinstalled, and it started working again.

Answer (score 10):

Ok after a whole productive day down the drain I got it to work.

First I uninstalled all traces of Genymotion and Virtualbox.
I then proceeded to install Genymotion and then Virtual Box again, but the previous version (4.2.18)

I ran Genymotion, Downloaded an Image, I got an error message about the network trying to run it. 
So I ran it Directly inside Virtual Box, It started up 100% with network and everything.
I shut it down, went to Image's settings and changed the first adapter to "Host-only".

I opened the Genymotion Launcher again and "Played" my device and it started up with no problems.

Comment: Just verified with a newer version 4.3.30 while the newer versions do not seem to work

Answer (score 8):

For those who are hitting this thread from Mac OSX with the same error message but a potentially different problem:

1) Check that you have opened GenyMotion through /Applications and that you have enabled the internet permissions

2) Install Virtual box from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. Once you download and install, retry running GenyMotion

3) If those do not work, try Mul0w''s suggestion:

`sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart`

Answer (score 6):

It happens when upgrading to el capitan from yosemite. Virtual box needs to be installed again. Reinstalling geny motion does nothing. You will keep all your virtual devices unchanged.

Comment: Updating VirtualBox  helped. I got kernel panic with v4.3.12 but as advised by [Genymotion's FAQs](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=compatible-virtualbox-versions#faq), I installed 4.3.26. it works fine now!

Comment: Installing VirtualBox 4.3.26 worked for me. More recent versions didn't work. You can get it from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3

Answer (score 4):

For Arch Linux try this :

```
sudo vboxreload
```

Answer (score 3):

Deleting Host-only network helped me.
1. Open Virtual Box
2. File->Preferences-> Network
3. Select the Host-only network and remove it.

Now try starting the Genymotion.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall VirtualBox with uninstaller (it comes with dmg), then install VirtualBox again. This has solved that issue for me.

Comment: I migrated over a slightly older version of VirtualBox when swapping macs and got this error. Reinstalling to the latest version fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual box version 4.3.28 worked with Genymotion 2.5.2 for me. Nothing else seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

i installed Oracle virtualbox ([Download link](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) then everything working fine

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 vboxdrv is not longer in /etc/init.d, therefore you must run this:

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Answer (score 0):

I also Struggled with el captain installed.
I installed the VirtualBox 4.3.26 version. Other latest versions doesnt worked for me.
It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

In GNU/Linux you can use this command

```
 /etc/init.d/virtualbox
```

Options

- start
- stop
- stop_vms
- restart
- force-reload
- status

for example

```
 /etc/init.d/virtualbox force-reload
```

**Good Luck**