# Genymotion launching but only a black sreen is visible

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have installed genymotion on my mac os.
I could install it successfully.
I added a new virtual device as well.
I can see that device running in my virtual box in running state.

In virtual box the preview which I see is correct.

Preview in virtual box:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0gp6uztuh0d7ys/Screenshot%202014-09-29%2012.50.56.png?dl=0

But the change doesn't reflect.

Current Screen which I can see:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/htdjqnvwt6jjlyp/Screenshot%202014-09-29%2012.52.09.png?dl=0

I've created Google Nexus 4 - 4.2.2 API 17.

Comment: AS i can see ur Genymotion didn't get an ip address from virtual box

Comment: Any suggestions of how I could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Follow following step to work genemotion.

1. Open Oracle VM virtual Box
2. **File** -> **Preferences** ( ctrl + g ) -> open one dialog box -> select **Network**  -> select Host only network choose you adapter ( there are three button on right side -add -remove -Edit host only nw.,

   If you dont have any adapter then create.
3. After selecting your adapater choose Edit **Edit host only network(space)**
4. Open one dialog box then choose **DHCP server**  choose **Enable Server** and fill all ip addresses.

   like

   IPv4 address/netmask: 192.168.56.1/255.255.255.0 (on Adapter tab)

   DHCP server enabled checked (on DHCP server tab)

   Server address/netmask: 192.168.56.100/255.255.255.0

   Server lower/upper address: 192.168.56.100/192.168.56.254
5. Give ok.
6. In starting of the oracle virtual machine there are different tab like General ,system , Display ,storage,Network etc.. **Click on Network**
7. Open one dialog box, select **Enable Network adapter**  attached to ->**host only network**
   and main thing is that in Name tab, choose adapter that you are choosing in preference **both adapter much be match**  example you choose virtualbox...2 then here also choose that one.
8. Ok.

Comment: I've already followed all these steps! But it really didn't help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629013/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-mavericks-vbox-is-setup-corr

Comment: I can't reload my virtual box: 
after following the above steps this is what  I get:
<https://www.dropbox.com/s/phmlsvpma7cas1q/Screenshot%202014-09-29%2013.09.46.png?dl=0>