# Genymotion Error: Unable to load Virtualbox engine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, genymotion

I am on Arch using VirtualBox from community repo and Genymotion from AUR.
Whenever i want to start a virtual device it says:

> Unable to load VirtualBox engine.
>
> Make sure that it is properly installed before starting Genymotion.
>
> For more information please refer to:
>   https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#vbox

I've already reinstalled everything nothing seems to work.

When i use

```
#vboxreload
```

"vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci vboxdrv" are loaded and genymotion works for this session until i reboot the system.

I use a virtualbox.conf at /etc/modules-load.d/ to load "vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci vboxdrv".

```
$cat /etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf 
vboxdrv\nvboxnetflt\nvboxnetadp\nvboxpci
```

I'm not a linux crack but I thought */etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf* would automatically load the modules - so i do not need to use #vboxreload after each reboot?

Comment: Got it. I am really dumb. Didnt see that i have copied the modules and \n was inserted instead of a new line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28736885/2652524 this also the same answer as jiajia jiang

Comment: Do not have enough rep here to add an answer. Came across this in google search. On Fedora had to put selinux into permissive mode.

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Comment: It fix the error, however, if I open a android 5.1 (Lollipop) the error comes up again, other versions were doing fine.

Answer (score 19):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the issue? He mentioned that he tried re-installing everything and that didn't help.

Comment: I have solved my problem myself (see comment in OP). Btw what you have posted may helps for debian or ubuntu based systems, but not arch

Comment: OP says  "I am on arch", why have you posted a debian / ubuntu solution?

Comment: Ohh yeah! thanks! if anyone have some issue with the first command, try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before it.

Answer (score 16):

In Linux VirtualBox Module compilation by running following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

If the above command fails, use:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

then restart virtualBox

```
/usr/bin/VirtualBox restart
```

Answer (score 10):

### If you have not vboxdrv file

Reinstall virtualbox-dkms:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: @luliia This removes currently installed virtualbox packages (downloaded from vb's website) and installs virtualbox and dependencies from ubuntu repo on my Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Ubuntu 18) I installed the last Vbox and after I disabled the secure boot from the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

You can have a problem like me. I had same errors but advices didn't help me.  But I found a lot of host-only networks in my virtualbox (you can check it, run virtualbox file->preference->networks->host-only networks).
I removed all "vboxnetXXX" and genymotion became to execute.

You can use sh script to remove it all:

```
for i in $(seq 0 255); do 
     VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Linux Mint** `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup`
  command worked for me. I guess same should work on Ubuntu and other debian builds.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem with VirtualBox itself and UEFI secure boot. I disabled it in the BIOS and it sorted out.

Answer (score -3):

Change the version of VirtualBox and start Genymotion again. It will work fine.