# Genymotion Error: VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, virtual, genymotion

I've tried searching, but cannot resolve this error message when running the Genymotion Android emulator:

[image: Image of error message]

Here is my directory layout if that helps:

[image: Directory layout]

Comment: Add some details, including what are you doing with adnroid in virtual box? Are you trying to run android OS on virtual box? What tutorial do you use for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Genymotion, "Unable to load VirtualBox engine." on Mavericks. VBox is setup correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629013/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-mavericks-vbox-is-setup-corr)

Answer (score 1):

There are two version of genymotion.One withe the virtual box and another without the virtual box.You should install the one with the virtual box in case it is not installed on your machine then reinstall genymotion with the virtual box from official website[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU5I1.png). This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#installing-genymotion
Check version of your VirtualBox + be sure that everything from this list is not about you:

> Genymotion cannot be run from a virtual machine. Indeed, it needs a direct access to the hardware in order to provide OpenGL acceleration. Running Genymotion from a virtual machine prevents it to directly access the hardware components. Therefore, Genymotion is incompatible when installed from VMWare, Parallels, Hyper-V or VirtualPC.