# Genymotion virtualization engine not found/plugin loading aborted on Mac

Tags: android, macos, virtual-machine, genymotion

I downloaded Genymotion but cannot get it to work. I keep on getting "virtualization engine not found, plugin loading aborted". I have uninstalled and reinstalled it, force quit and restarted it, and looked at other solutions to no avail. It seems to hit a snag [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whAtk.png).

I am running on a Mac, OSX Yosemite version 10.10.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Genymotion, "Unable to load VirtualBox engine." on Mavericks. VBox is setup correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629013/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-mavericks-vbox-is-setup-corr)

Comment: Check the VM compatible version https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You have to install Virtualbox to get genymotion to work.

Here is the link to download it https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Thank you, so I went to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and choose "VirtualBox 5.0.14 for OSX hosts" is that right?

Comment: Upgrade to latest geny and virtualbox solved my problem

Comment: Thank you!  This was helpful.  Why doesn't genymotion does not include this in it download of the product when it has a dependency on VirtualBox?

Comment: Compatible version here: https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions

Answer (score 8):

**MacOS [High Sierra]10.13.4**

1. Download Virtual Box 5.2.8 then tried to run Genymotion.
2. Download Genymotion 2.12 for personal use by signing up.
3. Restart the machine.
4. Change System Preferences at Security & Privacy the virtual box installation was being blocked. You can see than Oracle America..blah blah.. in General Tab. Just Allow it, you could see installation gets completed.
5. Now try to start Genymotion, it will install required plugins.
6. Start adding virtual devices.

Comment: Works perfectly with Mac 10.13.5, I wonder why genymotion doesn't have Virtual Box software embedded into its installer or at least should have mentioned in their installation guide.

Comment: You made my day. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Found this solution on another stackoverflow, but thought I'd help spread the good word. The problem has to do with `VBoxManager` installing to `/usr/local/bin` and genymotion expecting it in `/usr/bin`. So create a symlink and you're golden:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin`

It should also be noted that you should keep an eye on what version of VirtualBox is recommended by genymotion. Currently (as of July 31, 2017), it's [5.0.26](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.26/VirtualBox-5.0.26-108824-OSX.dmg).

Comment: "Operation not permitted" ... even with Sudo!

Comment: @Nathaniel got the same error, maybe because apple restricts it even to root user. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262686/genymotion-virtualization-engine-not-found-plugin-loading-aborted-on-mac

Comment: @naffiq you just linked to the question you are replying to :(

Comment: maybe you don't have sudo permissions? heh

Answer (score 3):

How i solved mine.

The problem is from Virtualbox DKMS
All you have to do is uninstall and install is back.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

Drop comment if its works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same issue on windows 8 by removing all old Virtual only Hosts .
This may help someone .

**Steps:**

- Open Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager
- Go to File -> Preference -> Network -> Hosts-Only Networks
- Remove all entries under this tab
- Click OK
- Restart Genymotion

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew for the rescue!
`brew cask install virtualbox`

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest way for me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Download Virtual box From

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%20OS%20X%20build%20instructions

Download Genymotion setup from

https://www.genymotion.com/download/

Follow this steps:

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/genymotion-android-emulator-for-os-x-windows-linux/

Answer (score 1):

I had lated VirtualBox installed but still Genymotion was throwing this error.

Installing the **right version (of VirtualBox)** as explained in the below link solved.
https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downloading and installing the latest Virtualbox and then launching Genymotion. everythnig worked perfectly. I hope this will help other who face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Download "with virtualbox" version if you have no virtual box installed on your system. Virtual box is necessary for Genymotion.

Link for Genymotion:  https://www.genymotion.com/download/